# connection fails to .asmx web service on localhost

Tags: android, asmx, ksoap

I've been accessing this web service successfully before with port:80, for some reasons I changed it to 8080 but now I can access web services locally on system, it throws below error on android phone.

```
**URL:** http://192.168.*.*:8080/webservice.asmx

java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.*.* (port 8080): connect     failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `uses-permission - android.permission.INTERNET` ([Details](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/AndroidManifest.html)) in `AndroidManifest.xml` and also test that `http://192.168.*.*:8080/webservice.asmx` url on web-browser. You can get the details reason form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device/16510143#16510143) also.

If above is not the case, If you are trying to connect localhost of your pc : then the localhost refers to the device on which the code is running.If you want to refer to the computer which is running the Android simulator, use the IP address 10.0.2.2 instead. You can read more from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Comment: I've already set permissions, I can see on web browsre, works fine on emulator, only issue is with android phone, BTW both computer/phone are under same WIFI

Comment: are your wifi password protected?

Comment: Your app might not be get connection, due to authentication. Can you please make sure.